# how to parse json data without semiquotes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

Hello i am trying to build a map using php json, when i tried to pass the value to javascript it is showing error

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token a

```
  {
            "map": "worldLow",
            "linkToObject": "Sharjah",
            "images": [{
                "id": "Sharjah",
                "color": "#000000",
                 svgPath: targetSVG,//error in this section as it is not passed without double quotes
                "title": "Sharjah",
                "latitude": "25.340225",
                "longitude": "55.395813",
                "scale": 1.5,
                "zoomLevel": 1.36,
                "zoomLongitude": -19.1341,
                "zoomLatitude": 49.1712,
    "lines": [ {
      "Projectname": "masjid",
      "latitudes": 12.2392,
      "longitudes": -0.84000000
     }
    ]},
     {
      svgPath: targetSVG,//error in this section as it is not passed without double quotes
      "Projectname": "masjid",
      "latitude": 12.2392,
      "longitude": -0.84000000,
    "selectable": "true" }]
}
```

how to pass the data without semiquotes

javascript

```
function setData(data){

                map.dataProvider = JSON.parse(data);
                map.validateNow();
            }
```

Comment: Obvioulsy you should check what generates such json and how to fix it instead of parsing this json.

Comment: Is svgPath and targetSVG both variables?

Comment: Are you building the (almost)JSON manually in your PHP? (If so, why?)

Comment: yes,because i am new to php..i only know this way

Comment: @garethb:yes both are variables

Comment: Are svgPath and targetSVG being declared in your php or in your javascript?

Comment: @garethb it is declared inside javascript,i solved the problem by adding the value to it...thank you